# Sample working CMS with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth

I'm looking for a sample project that uses Zend Framework so that I can see how masters do it.

I'm not looking for something that uses other stuff like smarty, or any other major library.

There are plenty of samples for different subjects on sites like zendcast.com but I need a full working solution.

I couldn't come up with anything like that by googling.

I came accross this a while ago, it has a sectoion on Central authentication 
http://www.zend.com/webinar/Framework/70170000000bEs9-webinar-secure-application-development-with-the-ZF-20100505.flv

Here are the notes, look at page 9
http://static.zend.com/topics/Webinar-Zend-Secure-Application-Development-with-the-Zend-Framework.pdf

Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Social Engine 4 is what you are asking for but its not free nor open source . The best application ever created using ZF has became even more popular then Zend itself ([google trend](http://www.google.com/trends?q=zend,magento)) its known as "Magento". Its open source  and based on best programming practices (design patterns) .

Comment: Magento is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

We are making a full open source CMS, based on Zend Framework: Centurion CMS (http://www.centurion-project.org/).

We are working on it since more than 2 years. The project is under the new BSD licence.

Feel free to try, use, pull feature, make some push request, criticize...

If you have any question use the our Google group: http://groups.google.com/group/centurion-project

Comment: Looks very promising. I want to use it but it's all in French.. The codebase is slightly different than what I'm used to with Zend. Can't login either. (checked it out from SVN yesterday).

Answer (score 1):

Social Engine 4 projects are built on Zend Framework.
Social Engine 3 used smarty but they decided to move to Zend.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [TomatoCMS](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://www.tomatocms.com/&ei=c61qTo_-DYihiAeK7M3dBA&usg=AFQjCNFafpq6XtXn1avo24elawsQnW3elQ&sig2=KRLNjynlJc_Hiu3_yrnu6A)

Answer (score 0):

[Pro Zend Framework Techniques: Build a Full CMS Project](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004SMQF5U)
I think this book will be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andryi. One note is that this book is written for Zend 1.x, not Zend 2.